# Handshake error in Webservice

Tags: web-services, sslhandshakeexception, remedy

Our integration partner was using our Web service with http: 8090 and now we are moving to https: 8443 so they tried to update the WS URL but they are getting "handshake error". They are asking whether they can still use http 8090. If we route any traffic coming from http 8090 to https 8443 in the webserver config, will they still get handshake error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a redirect, the server sends a `HTTP 302` which the client is obligated to follow, which means that they should still get the error. depending on your setup, and config, they may be able to send the request anyway, but if that works, then all your traffic is potentially insecure...